# How to manage a POST/PUT of an object that contains an abstract class with a discriminator table in Google Cloud Endpoints

Tags: java, jpa, jackson, google-cloud-endpoints, nosql

I'm trying to figure out how to get this to work. I have a class Connection which I want to create and persist in the datastore when a user makes a POST to our API. This is what the endpoint looks like:

```
@Api(
    name = "connect",
    version = "v1",
    defaultVersion = AnnotationBoolean.TRUE)
public class ConnectionEndpoint {

    @PersistenceContext
    protected static EntityManager entityManager = EMF.get().createEntityManager();

    ...

    @ApiMethod(
        name = "connections.create",
        path = "connections/{schema}",
        httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST)
    public Connection createConnection(@Named("schema") String schema, Connection connection) throws BadRequestException {

        // Code that checks permission and persists the connection if everything checks out

    }

    ...
}
```

The code in the endpoint doesn't fire because of this exception:

```
com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of com.analysis_engine.model.connect.BaseConnectionService, problem: abstract types can only be instantiated with additional type information
```

The Connection class looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Connection")
public class Connection {

    ...

    @OneToOne(orphanRemoval = true, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private BaseConnectionService service;

    ...
}
```

The BaseConnectionService class looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ConnectionService")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "Service", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, length = 64)
abstract public class BaseConnectionService {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected Key key;

    ...
 }
```

A class that extends the BaseConnectionService looks like this:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("Foo")
public class FooConnectionService extends BaseConnectionService {

    private String randomField;

}
```

So I want to be able to POST a Connection object with any kind of ConnectionService. It works if I do it all on the server side, the problem is in getting Jackson to deserialize the POSTed data correctly.